# Nodejs form GET request cannot show render page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to use nodejs and maybe the problem description is not that clear since I didn't post all the tasks I want to do, which maybe a bit overwhelming.

Here is the procedures:

1. *Input some parameters as "p" "t" "l" "u" "g" to server side using GET request.*
2. *Run a child-process 'planner()' with input as the parameters above.*
3. *Render the output to client side.*

And the problem is that, now I can see the planner results from console, but the client page will not direct to /planner page, or is there other way to show the result to client side, say show the console output in original index page?

index.ejs:

```
  <h2><%= title %></h2>
  <% for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {%>
       <li><%= data[i] %></li>
    <% } %>
  <form id="planner" method="GET" action="/planner">
    <input type="TEXT" id="p" size="40"><br>
    <input type="TEXT" id="t" size="40"><br>
    <input type="TEXT" id="l" size="40"><br>
    <input type="TEXT" id="u" size="40"><br>
    <input type="TEXT" id="g" size="40"><br>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

index.js

```
//planner() omitted...  

router.get('/planner', function(req, res){
var p=req.query.p;
var t=req.query.t;
var l=req.query.l;
var u=req.query.u;
var g=req.query.g;
console.log(p+"\n"+t+"\n"+l+"\n"+u+"\n"+g);

planner(p, t, l, u, g, function(planner_output){
    res.render('index', { 
        title: 'Planner Outputs:',
        data: planner_output 
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: You mention a page called `planner`, but your route seems to render `index`. Could that be it?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: @sg.cc Thanks for you response, I thought the 'index' is just a template and I have test if I use button with 'href="/planner"', I can get the rendered page. But here, I want to show the inputs from GET request and the submit button will not change the url to /planner instead of remaining 'localhost://3000'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

the input type must be submit

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the bug and it's really stupid, the res.render() of Express is good here but I mistake used type of the button:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

should be

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```